# MongoDB not recognized in fresh MEAN.io install

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I am getting this error when I try to `grunt` after installing MEAN.io:

```
Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
**Could not connect to MongoDB. Please ensure mongod is running and restart MEAN app.**
```

Do I need to take an extra step after installing MEAN.io in order for MongoDB to work?

Comment: Yes. You need to actually install MongoDB as the documentation says. MEAN.io is just the JavaScript stack, not the MongoDB server itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install mongodb as below:

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
$ echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/10gen.list
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen
```